# Retrieving list of children via Database Snapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having a bit of trouble retrieving child nodes via a query.

Here is my data structure:

[image: Firebase Structure]

I've managed to be able to successfully query and retrieve the data using the node highlighted "1" in the image above. Here is my code:

```
databaseRecipes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("recipe");

Query query = databaseRecipes.orderByChild(userId).equalTo(true);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Results found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                arrayList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Recipe recipe = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Recipe.class);
                    arrayList.add(recipe);
                }

                final RecipeAdapter recipeAdapter = new RecipeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recipeAdapter);
                recipeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else
            {
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No retreivable results :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

However I would rather keep all the 'favourites' together under their own separate node, as shown highlighted with "2". (There's only one child there for testing purposes, in practice there will be a lot more saved, so would be neater doing it this way.)

Using this code:

```
Query query = databaseRecipes.child("favourite").orderByChild(userId).equalTo(true);
```

I've also tried changing the reference to:

```
databaseRecipes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("recipe").child("favourite");
```

And query:

```
Query query = databaseRecipes.orderByChild(userId).equalTo(true);
```

But either way retrieves no results. I think my issue is with asking for children from the `DataSnapshot`:

```
for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
```

But I have been going round in circles all day now trying to find an alternative (I think I'm missing something really simple - which is even more annoying!), so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Apologies in advance for my awful paint skills!

**Edit**

If anyone else comes across this new to Firebase from an SQL background Alex gave solid advice.

New node created:

[image: New Data Structure]

Code to query node -

Database Reference:

```
databaseFvourites = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("favouriteRecipes").child(userId);
```

Query:

```
 Query query = databaseFvourites.orderByChild(userId).equalTo(true);
```

The data structure can probably be improved upon even more, but for my needs it does the job fine.

Comment: You made a POJO class for Recipies, you need to modify the POJO to include the favourite thing.
Now you can access the fav using recipe.getFavaourite();
Which will return bool

Comment: Alternately you could access `favourite` node inside loop like `dataSnapshot1.child("favourite")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the following query:

```
Query query = databaseRecipes.orderByChild(userId).equalTo(true);
```

Everything works fine because your `uid` is a property within your `-LY18 ... hFqO` object.

The following query:

```
Query query = databaseRecipes.child("favourite").orderByChild(userId).equalTo(true);
```

Won't work since you are missing a child, which is the actual pushed id `-LY18 ... hFqO`.

I think you are looking for a query that might look like this:

```
databaseRecipes.child($uid).child("favourite").orderByChild(userId).equalTo(true);
```

But unfortunately there are no wildcards in Firebase. So you cannot filter items based on a property that exists within a map. This is actually possible in Cloud Firestore but regarding your use-case, you should consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup by creating another node named `favoriteUsers` in which you should add all favorite user `recipes`. This practice is called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. If you are new to NoQSL databases, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) for a better understanding.

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, I appreciate it.

I'm completely new to NoSQL, so far I've managed to succeed with a rather haphazard trial by error approach, but I can see now my data structure definitely has a lot of room for improvement!

Will check out the video you recommended and research into denormalization.